# JS Android Service (background task) with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, notifications

I would like to set up notifications on my PhoneGap application.

The notifications must also be present when the application is closed.

For this I had thought about writing a script by JS making a regular call ( every 1 or 2 hours ) to my API to check whether the user should be notified or not.

It involves using a JS script that runs in background.

**Is it possible? and if yes, how ?**
**Is it possible with this plugin ? : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/README.md**

*I think I have to create a service. But if I create a service plugin on PhoneGap can I still execute the javascript.
Or can I create a Node.js service ?*

This script would:

- check whether or not the user is "Stay signed in".
  If so, then check the presence of a notification, otherwise, sending a notification to the user log, and check the "Stay signed in".
- make an AJAX call to the API to retrieve notification informations (title, message ... )